# Using only some attributes for clustering in R

Tags: r, cluster-computing, data-science

I have some data with several attributes. I would like to try hierarchical clustering. Currently, I am using the following line

```
hc <- hclust(dist(users), method = "average")
```

However, this uses all attributes, including some irrelevant ones, such as user ID, to infer the distances.

How do I tell the `dist` function to only use some attributes?

Comment: Is using simply `dist(users[, c("attr1", "attr4")])` rather than `dist(users)` somehow not acceptable in your case?

Comment: Since I am not using the information about names of the columns, wouldn't I lose the information which object is which?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. Do you mean using `hc` to trace back which columns you used? If so, `hc$call` may help with that.